# Reward for not fleeing

Tags: practical-islam, martyr

I heard if someone who catches the recent corona virus and does not flee from it. He gets a martyr's reward in Islam.
It makes sense right?

Comment: If the person fleas somewhere, more people will catch corona so makes sense

Comment: yes, there is a hadith which say's that they will be considered as martyr's

Comment: What is the hadith?